# How to update js object type variable via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a **javascript variable** that is created in **php**

`echo "var".$locallist."=".create_js_variable($locallist,$db2_list_all,'db2');`

and it looks in html page source code like

```
var locallist={
  'CARINYA':[['2011-08-24-09-22 - w','20110824092216w'],['2011-08-18-13-15','20110818131546']],
  'COVERNAN':[['2011-03-02-12-28','20110302122831']],
  'DAVID':[['2010-12-22-19-43','20101222194348'],['2010-12-08-14-10','20101208141035']]};
```

Now I want to update the variable on button click via **ajax**

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text',
        url: url,
        data: {
            what: 'db2list', 
            t: Math.random() 
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus){
            locallist = data;                   
            console.log(locallist);
        }
    });
```

and the **ajax calls this php code** (note that it's the same php function that is called)

```
if($what == 'db2list') {
    $db2_list_all = get_db2_database_list();
    echo create_js_variable($locallist,$db2_list_all,'db2');
}
```

Console.log reports that

- before update the variable is an **object**
- after update it is a **text**

How can I fix that? So my other javascript code works again?

Comment: Make sure you use `"` in your json and not `'` thank you @Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, look at your ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'text',
    url: url,
    data: {
        what: 'db2list', 
        t: Math.random() 
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus){
        locallist = data;                   
        console.log(locallist);
    }
});
```

Notice you've got the dataType as text? It's going to bring the data in and treat it as text. Try changing the dataType to 'json'. That will convert the data that was brought in to a regular 'ol object, just like what you already have.

Comment: Do I have to change anything on server side? Can I fix it inside javascript?

Comment: You shouldn't have to change anything server side. If it doesn't work though, a relatively easy fix is to put this into your code just before you spit anything out: header("Content-type: application/json");

Comment: Or just header("Content-type: text/plain"); I like this one because then I can actually see the page if I load it up on my browser.

Comment: It works ok now but it seems to me that other js function didn't pick up the update. I change select options on click in this function. I can see that ajax returned correct data but the variable's content is the same.

Comment: So after changing the type to json success function is not executed.

Comment: Can you paste in exactly what the server returns from an ajax request? If the success function isn't firing, that can mean that jquery detected a bad response.

Comment: @Radek let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2882/discussion-between-stephen-and-radek)

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX-request has a type `dataType: 'text',`
Change it to JSON :)

Comment: Do I have to change anything on server side? Can I fix it inside javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Use `dataType: 'json'`.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    data: {
        what: 'db2list', 
        t: Math.random() 
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus){
        locallist = data;                   
        console.log(locallist);
    }
});
```